# How to know commited memory (shared and private) of process in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory

I need to know total committed memory size (shared and private)
The private I extract from  `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` using `PagefileUsage`
How can I know the (total) shared memory of the process ?

Comment: You posted this twice - mis-click?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the process of shared memory: `CreateFileMapping` creates a shared memory space; `OpenFileMapping` opens shared memory and returns a HANDLE handle; [MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) obtains the memory mapped to the program, which can be read and written.

In the MSDN of [MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile): To obtain the size of a view, use the [VirtualQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) function. The return value of the `VirtualQuery` function represents the size actually filled to the second parameter, not the size of the memory. The real memory information is viewed in the second parameter after filling

```
SIZE_T VirtualQuery(
  LPCVOID                   lpAddress,
  PMEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer,
  SIZE_T                    dwLength
);
```

Here is the code:

```
HANDLE hMap = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 1000, NULL);
PVOID pData = MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mem_info;
int nBufferSize = VirtualQuery(pData, &mem_info, sizeof(mem_info));
UnmapViewOfFile(pData); //you could place a breakpoint here
CloseHandle(hMap);
```

When the breakpoint is triggered, check the memory data of `mem_info`, pay special attention to the `RegionSize` member in the structure.

The system memory is allocated according to the granularity as the smallest unit. The normal granularity of a 32-bit system is 4kb, so the memory after a successful application is generally an integer multiple of 4kb. So, the code above applies for 1000 bytes, but the system actually allocates 4kb.

Comment: I don't see how this answers (or even relates to) OP's question about the total shared commit size. Note that, just as private commit doesn't only cover allocations directly made by OP's code alone, shared committed memory does not necessarily come from `CreateFileMapping` calls in OP's own code. It can include shared areas made/used by the system, or by other DLLs loaded in OP's process memory space. You can't `VirtualQuery` those if you don't find what and where they are, first.